# descriptor 'append' requires a 'list' object but received a 'str'

Tags: python

I am doing an assignment in coursera in python course, 
here is the problem:
10.2 Write a program to read through the mbox-short.txt and figure out the distribution by hour of the day for each of the messages. You can pull the hour out from the 'From ' line by finding the time and then splitting the string a second time using a colon.
From stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za Sat Jan  5 09:14:16 2008
Once you have accumulated the counts for each hour, print out the counts, sorted by hour as shown below. 
I write this code but there is an error in line 11 and I can not figure it out, hope someone help me !
the error is :descriptor 'append' requires a 'list' object but received a 'str

```
name = raw_input("Enter file:")
if len(name) < 1 : name = "mbox-short.txt"
handle = open(name)
ls = list()
dic = dict()
for line in handle:
    word = line.rstrip().split()
    if word[0] == 'From':
        piece = word[5].split(':')
        hour = piece[0]
        list.append(hour)  ####there is a problem
for element in list:
    dic[element] = dic.get(element,0) + 1
print dic
```

Comment: it should be `ls.append` not `list.append`. And consequently, you should be iterating through `ls` in your second for loop, not `list`

Comment: Also, consider using variable names reflecting what they contain/represent, not just a variation from their type. For example: `hours_list` and `hours_count_dict`

Comment: Thanks for you guys answers!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant append to "list".  List is an "off limit word" for python, just like you cant call a variable str.  As one of the comments said, I think you mean ls.append not list.append.

Comment: Its not that you CANT do it, it's more that you SHOULDNT do it. Overriding those words (`list`, `str`, etc) are actually allowed and do not throw errors, but you then lose the ability to use those words as they are (which are class decorators)

Comment: Depending on your editor, you are not allowed and an error is thrown.